# C++: Saving data in parallel arrays

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm having a bit of trouble with parallel arrays. In this function I'm writing for homework, we're to create a menu-based input for entering book data. The book data will be stored in various parallel arrays, i.e. one for title, one for ISBN, one for author and etc.

My problem is that at the end of this do-while loop, the data the user just input is to be saved into the next entry of the arrays. But it just seems to be overwriting the last entry (or it ONLY writes in the last entry of the array, I'm not sure). I tested using a looping a cout statement through the arrays and all I get is the last entry... Any pointers in the right direction would be awesome, thanks!

Sorry if the formatting gets butchered on the code, this is also my first time posting on stackoverflow.

```
void addBook (string bookTitle [], string isbn [], string author [], string publisher [], string dateAdded [], int qtyOnHand [], double wholesale [], double retail [], int& bookCount)

{
int userChoice = -1;
int pos = 0;
int len = 30;

string tempBookTitle = "EMPTY";
string tempISBN = "EMPTY";
string tempAuthor = "EMPTY";
string tempPublisher = "EMPTY";
string tempDateAdded = "EMPTY";
int tempQtyOnHand = 0;
double tempWholesale = 0;
double tempRetail = 0;

int bookIndex = 0;

do
(  {
system ("CLS");

cout << "******************************************************************************" << endl
     << "*                          SERENDIPITY BOOKSELLERS                           *" << endl
     << "*                                 ADD BOOK                                   *" << endl
     << "*                   DATABASE SIZE: " << setw (8) << DBSIZE << "CURRENT BOOK COUNT: " << setw (8) << bookCount << "      *" << endl
     << "*                                                                            *" << endl
     << "*                                                --PENDING VALUES--          *" << endl
     << "*                                                                            *" << endl
     << "*  <1> Enter Book Title              >  " << setw (37) << tempBookTitle.substr (pos, len) << "*" << endl
     << "*  <2> Enter ISBN                    >  " << setw (37) << tempISBN << "*" << endl
     << "*  <3> Enter Author                  >  " << setw (37) << tempAuthor << "*" << endl
     << "*  <4> Enter Publisher               >  " << setw (37) << tempPublisher << "*" << endl
     << "*  <5> Enter Date Added (MM/DD/YYYY) >  " << setw (37) << tempDateAdded << "*" << endl
     << "*  <6> Enter Quantity on Hand        >  " << setw (37) << tempQtyOnHand << "*" << endl
     << "*  <7> Enter Wholesale Price         >  " << setw (37) << tempWholesale << "*" << endl
     << "*  <8> Enter Retail Price            >  " << setw (37) << tempRetail << "*" << endl
     << "*  <9> Save Book to Database                                                 *" << endl
     << "*  <0> Return to Inventory Menu                                              *" << endl
     << "*                                                                            *" << endl
     << "******************************************************************************" << endl
     << "                                CHOICE (0-9): ";
)

cin >> userChoice;

while (cin.fail () || userChoice < 0 || userChoice > 9)
{
  cout << "Please input correct OPTION: ";
  cin.clear ();
  cin.ignore ();
  cin >> userChoice;
}

cout << endl;

switch (userChoice)
{
  case 1:
    cout << "Enter Book Title: ";
    cin.ignore ();
    getline (cin, tempBookTitle);
    break;
  case 2:
    cout << "Enter ISBN: ";
    cin.ignore ();
    getline (cin, tempISBN, '\n');
    break;
  case 3:
    cout << "Enter Author: ";
    cin.ignore ();
    getline (cin, tempAuthor, '\n');
    break;
  case 4:
    cout << "Enter Publisher: ";
    cin.ignore ();
    getline (cin, tempPublisher, '\n');
    break;
  case 5:
    cout << "Enter Date Added (MM/DD/YYYY): ";
    cin.ignore ();
    getline (cin, tempDateAdded, '\n');
    break;
  case 6:
    cout << "Enter Quantity-on-Hand: ";
    cin >> tempQtyOnHand;
    break;
  case 7:
    cout << "Enter Wholesale Price: ";
    cin >> tempWholesale;
    break;
  case 8:
    cout << "Enter Retail Price: ";
    cin >> tempRetail;
    break;

  //THIS IS MY PROBLEM CASE HERE// 
  case 9:
    bookTitle [bookIndex] = tempBookTitle;
    isbn [bookIndex] = tempISBN;
    author [bookIndex] = tempAuthor;
    publisher [bookIndex] = tempPublisher;
    dateAdded [bookIndex] = tempDateAdded;
    qtyOnHand [bookIndex] = tempQtyOnHand;
    wholesale [bookIndex] = tempWholesale;
    retail [bookIndex] = tempRetail;
    bookCount++;
    bookIndex++;
    break;
 }

}
while (userChoice != 0);
{
  return;
}
}
```

Comment: `do (  {` -- Does this compile?  Where did you get the notion that a parenthesis is valid when invoking a `do-while` loop?

Comment: it compiles, that parenthesis is just from me copying and pasting over code and thinking about adding a comment but forgetting to delete it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Well the code above doesn't compile, but it's pretty clear what the problem is

```
void addBook (string bookTitle [], ... , int& bookCount)
{
    ...
    int bookIndex = 0;
    ... 
    case 9:
        bookTitle [bookIndex] = tempBookTitle;
        ...
        bookCount++;
        bookIndex++;
        break;
```

Your `bookIndex` always starts at zero even if your `bookCount` is more than zero. Just drop `bookIndex` and use `bookCount` throughout.

```
void addBook (string bookTitle [], ... , int& bookCount)
{
    ...
    case 9:
        bookTitle [bookCount] = tempBookTitle;
        ...
        bookCount++;
        break;
```